# How to change server root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webrick

I am using rails 4 with server webrick.  After starting the server via command line using `rails s`, the console displays the following:

```
kalinin@kalinin ~/rails/admin_book $ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on c
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-09-22 15:43:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-22 15:43:27] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-09-22 15:43:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=14160 port=3000
```

I want to change server root from:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

to:

```
http://localhost:3000/public
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure webrick by passing the correct document root:

```
require 'webrick'

root = File.expand_path '~/public'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => root
```